# Magento: How to create new URL with slashes (folders)?

Tags: apache, url, magento, magento-1.7

I'm using magento 1.7.0.2 and I have an [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pagseguro-by-os-studios-1439.html) that requires me to set up to URLs:

```
http://www.yourstore.com/pagseguro/pay/success/
```

This url will be used from a third party to API to redirect back to my site. I'm unable to set it up.

I tried to set up a CMS page, but it does not seem to work with any slashes. I was able to set up a `pagseguro` as the key URL in a CMS page, but whenever I try `pagseguro/pay/success/` as the key URL or even `pagseguro/` , it does not work.

How can I achieve this? I have "Use web server rewrite" enables, but even disabling it, it does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either url rewrite or extension where `pagseguro` will be extension frontName, `pay` - controller and `success` - action. But as long as you only need a single page I suggest url rewrite. So assuming you have your `pagseguro` CMS page set up, go to `Admin\Catalog\Url Rewrite Management` and add an entry:

```
Type: Custom
ID Path: whatever
Request Path: pagseguro/pay/success
Target Path: pagseguro
Redirect: No
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I finally don't need to set up this new page.